# Как вывести на экран размер скидки в интернет-магазине?

Tags: php, ооп, opencart, format

Работаю с `OpenCart`. Если кто знает - подскажите как с помощью ООП вывести размер скидки на экран. Есть 2 поля - цена и размер скидки. Формулу по которой формируется цена с учетом скидки я сделал. Как теперь рядом с ценой вывести на экран размер введенной скидки?

Небольшой кусок кода если необходимо:

```
<div class="price"><?php echo $text_price; ?>
    <?php if (!$special) { ?>
    <?php echo $price?>
    <?php if (!empty($product_info['sell'])) {
          $product_info['price'] = $product_info['price'] - $product_info['sell'];
        }
    ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
```

Comment: Это Вы тренируетесь или родные скидки и акции в OpenCart не устраивают?

Comment: Тренируюсь конечно=)